# Ajax response empty ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, cookies, asp.net-session

I have some ajax on my asp.net page that requests another entire asp.net page.
If no cookie is sent with that request (the cookie contains the sessionID)
the response from the server is empty.

Why is that? How can I fix that.

Comment: Please show some code. Enable the cookie reading on the asp.net page that read the ajax call.

Comment: Hey. I found the solution. Session timeout cause a 302.